# Why does the exponent drop when "ln-ing" something?

Tags: calculus

When differentiating implicit functions, you are supposed to ln both sides of the equation and then solve for y'.

Now when you add ln to something like.. say $x^a$ how come when you add ln to it you end up with the a dropping down and the ln just added onto the x like this? 
$$ a (ln(x))$$

Comment: $\ln(x^a)=a\ln x$ is a fundamental property of logarithms. It's one of their main uses in practice. It is the same property as $(e^y)^a=e^{ay}$, only written differently.

Comment: OH I should've known that, thanks! For some reason when I read "Now add ln" to both sides I just wondered why doesn't it mean encapsulate the whole function inside ln. Is that a weird thing to think? Does it mean that my understanding of logarithms/derivatives is wrong?

Comment: No, not really. As far as I can see, you may have had some random spell of notational misunderstanding. It could conceivably be part of something bigger, but I see no reason to extrapolate from this to a fundamental lack of understanding logarithms just from one case.

Comment: If you are at the level of differentiating implicit functions, you *must* know about the properties of the logarithm.

Comment: The rule $\ln(x^a) = a \ln(x)$ is a natural counterpart to the rule $\ln(xy) = \ln(x)+\ln(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

This does not only occur in calculus. It is a fundamental property of logarithms, coming from their very definition. Recall that
$$\log_ab=c\iff a^c=b.$$
Also recall the exponential property
$$ x^{a+b}=x^ax^b. $$
Now suppose $a=x^m$ and $b=x^n$. Then
$$ \log_x ab=\log_x\left(x^mx^n\right)=\log_x\left(x^{m+n}\right)=m+n=\log_x m+\log_x n. $$
Now applying this property multiple times, we get that for positive integers $n$, and arbitrary base $a$,
$$ \log_a(x^n)=\underbrace{\log_a x+\log_a x+\cdots+\log_a x}_{n\text{ times}}=n\log_a x. $$
Of course, taking $a=e$ we get the identity in your question,
$$ \ln(x^a)=a\ln(x).$$